# LabelFor + EditorFor on the same line?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ticket)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ticket)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ticket)
</div>
```

How do I get the label and checkbox(in this case its a checkbox) on the same line? I have tried removing the divs and they still come out on different lines.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the divs separating them, this works for me, I get `Ticket []` with this.

Also, use `CheckBoxFor` if you know it is a `CheckBox`

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ticket)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Ticket)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ticket)
</div>
```

I have also used this code as the OP stated this is his code

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.Label("SMS Alerts?")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetAll)
</div>
```

I get `GetAll []`

`GetAll` is a `bool` in my ViewModel

Also used this

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GetAll)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetAll)
</div>
```

I get `GetAll []`

And this

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GetAll)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetAll)
</div>
```

I get `GetAll []`

In every case my tests are label and checkbox are inline

Comment: I just retried it as:

    `<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Label("SMS Alerts?")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SmsAlerts)
        </div>`

And There is a linebreak between them. I'm not sure why this is happening for me =/.

Comment: I have tried it using that very code and I still get inline just fine. Are those fields wrapped up in some other element that maybe setting the style?

Comment: I used  `<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("SMS Alerts?")
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetAll)
    </div>` where GetAll is a boolean field on my view. I get `SMS Alerts? []`

Comment: Your comment about another element helped me discover the source. If I remove the <fieldset> tag around all of my inputs this behavior goes away. Do you know why the <fieldset> tag might cause this to happen? thank you for your help.

Comment: The fieldset is only meant to group related elements together, it draws a line around them, like a groupbox. Maybe that Fieldset was forcing a wrap of elements as the width may have been too narrow.

Answer (score 6):

Removing the  didn't work for my app, but adding `new { @style = "display:inline-block" }` as the second argument on the `LabelFor()` did.

I prefer the checkbox before the label so it would be:

```
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GetAll)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GetAll, new { @style = "display:inline-block" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case just add the row to the main div because I want to use the col-md-2

classes so after searching for solution when use col-*

classes then the parent element needs the row classes :

it was without row class

```
<div class="form-group ">
```

and just add row class :

```
 <div class="form-group row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BATCH_NO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BATCH_NO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BATCH_NO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```